# CSS3 progressive transforms for unknown amount of children

Tags: css

I've been playing with progressive transforms in CSS coupled with transitions. It's looking pretty good so far, but I'd like to know how I can make it generic - that is, for any amount of children.

The dabblet/gist is [here](http://dabblet.com/gist/2572679) - and you can see straight away that this is hardcoded for a small amount of children. I don't want to have to write `div+div+div+div....` rules as below - there's probably a neat way to achieve this, but would welcome any ideas.

```
.fan:hover div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
    top: -10px;
    left: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 10px rgba(128,128,128,0.3);
}
.fan:hover div+div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    top: -15px;
    left: 10px;
}
.fan:hover div+div+div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    top: -20px;
    left: 15px;
}
```

edit: I realise they are just webkit rules for now too ;)

Comment: I'd probably use JS to make it dynamic, but it would be interesting to see if it's possible with pure CSS.

Comment: exactly - with JS, it's trivial, but, would be nice to know if this can be done with css.

Comment: At first, I thought maybe [using a](http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/) [CSS](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/) [Counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Counters), but they only work for CSS-generated content. (`:before` and `:after`) Can't think of any way to accomplish this (admittedly handy) effect via CSS only, besides maybe using `:nth-child(...)`, but that still doesn't avoid the multiple declarations being necessary.

Comment: Currently there is no way to do this in pure CSS, as it's very limited in terms of such things as [variables](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables) and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at your code:

http://dabblet.com/gist/2574800

For the second, modified fan, only the `.fan:hover div` rule applies, but thanks to nesting the transform rules get applied multiple times on your divs, so the first div gets rotated 10deg, the second 10+10deg and so on...
You might hav to adjust the rules further, but the principle is clear i think.

Comment: yep that works - i don't like the structure, but can live with it :)